# insert string that match regular expression

Tags: java

My program takes a string input from a user. If the input string matches the regular expression then it should be inserted into the arrayList.

I wrote that following. But, it does not work:

```
        if( element.matches("[a-zA-Z]"));
        {
        set.add(element);
        }
```

Comment: Can your provide more code, i.e. the definition of element and set, and then provide the actual input that is not working?

Comment: I remember JCP certification had a question with the same semicolon bug. They of course made it intentionally to test the understanding of language basics.

Answer (score 4):

If that's actually how your code is written then the `element` will always be added to the `set`. You need to remove the `;` at the end of the first line for the conditional to work:

```
if (element.matches("[a-zA-Z]")) {
    set.add(element);
}
```

If you're trying to match more than more character you likely want `"[a-zA-Z]+"` for the expression.

Comment: To match one or more character, regex should be `"[a-zA-Z]+"`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot the `+` sign, meaning "once or more":

```
if (element.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {..}
```

(and of course, as the example above shows, you have to get rid of the semicolon)